# How to prevent code from executing before a JQuery plugin is finished saving a cookie

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I have the following function called HowTo that is executed with a onclick event, a function within it requires the JQuery plugin [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) which is: "*A simple, lightweight jQuery plugin for reading, writing and deleting cookies.*" :

```
function HowTo(){

   $largeAmountOfHTML = document.getElementById("element").innerHTML;

   $.cookie("nameOfCookie", $largeAmountOfHTML);

   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "path/to/serverside/script.php",
       async:false,
   });


   window.location.href='anotherPage.php';

};
```

The function firstly retrieves a substantial amount of HTML and assigns it to the variable $largeAmountOfHTML. Then using the JQuery function $.cookie() declared in [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)'s library the function saves the value of $largeAmountOfHTML to the cookie nameOfCookie. Then the function makes an AJAX call that executes a serverside php script which retrieve the cookie data and saves the content to a MYSQL database. Once complete the function directs the current window to anotherPage.php.

The function runs smoothly with no console errors declared. However, when $largeAmountOfHTML reaches a certain size [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) cannot assign the cookie fast enough before the serverside script attempts to retrieve it. [jquery.cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) does not list any methods I can use to prevent this from happening.

Once $largeAmountOfHTML is large enough and cannot be saved to the cookie in time the severside script declares the this error:

```
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: nameOfCookie in <b>localhost/path/to/serverside/script.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: Setting a cookie is a synchronous action, as far as I know. However cookies have a limited size in most browsers (~4KB). Your cookie is probably just too big and cannot be stored as such.

Comment: Why are you not sending this data via POST? what is the point of using a Cookie to store this data ?

Comment: @ Julian Descottes: I have updated my answer to reflect on your concerns. I will cross that bridge when I get to it.

Comment: @ Christopher Morrissey: Storing the data in a cookie is necessary as it is used soon on anotherPage.php as well. To save bandwidth and for performance reasons I dont want to retrieve it from the database straight after.

Comment: @Cool2beblue then... store it in the session? storing it in a cookie means all that data has to be sent back and forth with every request! (including ajax requests)

Comment: @ Kevin B  It's used in a javascript app. The cookie data is not needed server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wont deferred.done work? Then just call the serverside code in the callback [deferred.done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)